# Fable Theme Page Builder Layout got disoriented after Wordpress update. All tab menu of the editor shifted to right

Tags: wordpress

Recently I updated wordpress and its now running on version: 6.1.1. After this update I noticed that the Page Builder layout changed and I am not able to edit any pages like I was able to do previously. What might be causing this issue ? Can anyone please guide me ?

I have attached screenshot of the layout which I am getting now and which I used to get previously.

[image: Current Layout]

[image: Previous Layout]

Thank you.

I updated all the plugins and reinstalled the wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Yay !!! I got the solution. One of my friend is also using the same theme. Her layout was perfect and theme was working fine as expected. I crossed check plugins she installed and I have installed. In the comparison I found that I have one extra plugin which I installed so I simply deactivated that plugin and now my theme is working fine like before.

The plugin which I deactivated is **Nested Shortcodes by Outerbridge**

Thank you.